# $state.go when pass the something, it does not work

Tags: angularjs, controller, ionic-framework, state

I want to check the current user when use my app. So, I write the boot code for my app. But something wrong(controller can not be loaded.) when I pass something in url.

```js
/*
 * boot controller
 */
.controller('BootCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, $state){
 
        console.log('BootCtrl Working.');

 // check login
 var currentUser = AV.User.current();
 if(currentUser){
  // success login
  $state.go("app.playlists");
 }else{
  // failed login
  $state.go("login");
 }
})
```

```js
// boot state
.state('boot', {
url: '/',
template: 'system booting...',
controller: 'BootCtrl'
});

// default match
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
```

> my issue like that, when I link the url **http://localhost:8000/#/**, it works fine, it will be successful to go to **login** state.(means boot controller is working.)
>
> but when I pass something doesn't match the state like that **http://localhost:8000/#/sdfsadfasdfsdfdsfdf**, it doesn't go to **login** state, and the boot controller doesn't work.

*if I want to check login when user open app, what should I code?*

Answer (score 0):

Pass the parameter in the app.js also the one you are passing in the $state.go.Suppose you are passing 'id' in your controller you need to pass that in the app.js like /nextstate/:id

Comment: That does not work, but I find the solution which uses onEnter